# Django: Optional model form field

Tags: python, django, forms, python-2.7

I have a model form in my application, and I want two of my model form fields to be optional, i.e. the users could leave those two form fields blank and the Django form validation shouldn't raise an error for the same.

I have set `blank = True` and `null = True` for those two fields as follows:

```
questions = models.CharField(blank=True, null = True, max_length=1280)
about_yourself = models.CharField(blank=True, null = True, max_length=1280)
```

forms.py

```
questions = forms.CharField(help_text="Do you have any questions?", widget=forms.Textarea)
about_yourself = forms.CharField(help_text="Tell us about yourself", widget=forms.Textarea)
```

However, if these two fields are left blank on submission, a `This field is required` is raised.

What seems to be wrong here? How can I set optional model form fields in Django?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
questions = forms.CharField(help_text="Do you have any questions?", widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)
about_yourself = forms.CharField(help_text="Tell us about yourself", widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)
```

Comment: For those wondering WHY this answer is correct refer to @Galia-Ladiray-Weiss below who explains how you are refining the model as a form which inherits the fields.Field defaults.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is because you re-define the fields in your Form, so if for example your model name is MyModel, and then you simply define a ModelForm

```
MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

it will work, but since you defined the fields, it uses the defaults of the django fields.Field, which is required=True

You can simply add required=True to your fields definitions

Comment: This answer suited me because it's for form-defined fields and I needed required=False

Answer (score 2):

I think u need to add `required=False` parameter for forms.

Like this:

```
questions = forms.CharField(help_text="Do you have any questions?", widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)
about_yourself = forms.CharField(help_text="Tell us about yourself", widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)
```