# Defined optional form field not being so optional

Tags: django, django-forms

I looked over this topic [Django: Optional model form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539694/django-optional-model-form-field) but didn't help solve my problem.

I need the field `timeout` to be optional, meaning when user leaves it blank
it will default to 10

This is what I've got so far:

models:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    timeout = models.IntegerField(default=10)
```

modelform:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # ...
    timeout = forms.IntegerField(
       widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
             'class': 'form-control',
             'placeholder': 'Enter Timeout (optional)'}),
       required=False, label='')
    # ...

    class Meta:
        # ...
```

view:

```
class CreateTestSuite(FormView):
    template_name = 'create_test_suite.html'
    form_class = MyModelForm
    success_url = '/list'
    context_object_name = 'user_id'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_id'] = self.request.user.id
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()  #  this is where form submission throws an error
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
```

The traceback says `NOT NULL constraint failed: timeout`

So where else do I need to specify that the form field is optional and defaults to 10 in the database if left blank ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring because the field in DB can't be null, although in the form it is not required.

As timeout an optional field, you should make it nullable:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    timeout = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)
```

---

Alternatively, if you still want to put some value in `timeout` field in DB, you can override the `save()` method:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    timeout = models.IntegerField(default=10)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.timeout:
             self.timeout = 10
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It is optional in the sense that user doesn't have to fill it out but some value has to be in the database hence `default=10`

Comment: I'm gonna tick this off but you're sharing credit with @Anjaneyulu Batta as his suggestion is also valid with giving the user an idea what the timeout is to start with. I take it as the attribute `default=10` isn't really doing its job.

Answer (score 1):

As you made timeout as optional field. You have to provide an initial value to it (i.e `initial=10`) like below.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    timeout = forms.IntegerField(
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Enter Timeout (optional)'}),
                required=False, label='', initial=10)
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values

Comment: Me & @ruddra owe you a beer as your suggestion is also perfectly valid.