# Cannot make ForeignKey optional...?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my django application, I defined a model:

```
class CourtOrder(models.Model):
    sign = models.CharField('Court Order Sign', max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(CourtOrderCategory, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    description = models.CharField('Description', blank=True, max_length=50)
    show_in_sidebar = models.BooleanField('Show in Sidebar', default=True)
    institution = models.ForeignKey(Institution, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date = models.DateField('Court Order date', blank=True, null=True)
    effect_date = models.DateField('Court Order Date of Effect', blank=True, null=True)
    next_update = models.DateField('Next Update', blank=True, null=True)
    duty_scopes = models.ManyToManyField(DutyScope, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.ManyToManyField(Note, blank=True, null=True)
    records = models.ManyToManyField(Record, blank=True, null=True)
```

The class contains a number of other entries, but I'm having trouble with the two `ForeignKeys`.
I already read this post:
[How to make the foreign key field optional in Django model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619984/how-to-make-the-foreign-key-field-optional-in-django-model)

But did not have any success, the debugger still tells me that my form is invalid if these values are not set. I ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` several times and I also tried to change the `on_delete`value to `SET_NULL`to see if my mistake was there, but that did not change the outcome.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Thanks a lot for the replies. I edited the text above to show the whole model. When looking at my forms.py, I realized that I had customized the two entries that give me trouble:

```py
class CourtOrderForm(ModelForm):
    institution = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Institution.objects.filter(category__category__icontains="gericht"))
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CourtOrderCategory.objects.order_by('name'))
    
    class Meta:
        model = CourtOrder
        fields = (
            'sign',
            'category',
            'description',
            'show_in_sidebar',
            'institution',
            'date',
            'effect_date',
            'next_update',
            'duty_scopes',
            'notes',
            'records',
        )
```

The overall idea of this is to enter a new court order into my webapp. I want to first only show a modal that asks for the court order sign and then show the rest of the form fields. The exchange is done via htmx. I still have several issues to tackle, this is a work in progress (aka "still a mess"). I just could not find out why I kept getting

`UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'courtorder' where it is not associated with a value`in the console.
The debugger gave me this error:
errors: {'category': ['This field is required.'], 'institution': ['This field is required.']}
Because the form was not valid, the program did not define `courtorder` which let to the error message in the console.

The template:

```html
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% if sign_submitted %}

<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 id="modal-title" class="modal-title">Einzelheiten zu Gerichtsbeschluss {{ courtorder.sign }}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method=POST hx-post="/add_court_order/{{ record.pk }}/" hx-target="#courtorder-list" >
            {% csrf_token %}

            <!--
            <div id="courtorder-categories">
                <label for="#courtorder-category" class="form-label">Kategorie</label>
                <div id="courtorder-category" class="input-group mb-4">
                    <span class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="bi bi-bookmark-fill"></i>
                    </span>
                    
                        <select id="courtorder-category-select" class="form-select"
                            hx-get="/courtorder_check_additional_fields/" 
                            hx-trigger="change" 
                            hx-target="#courtorder-additional-fields"
                        >
                            <option selected>Kategorie auswählen...</option>
                            {% for category in categories %}
                                <option value="{{ category.name }}">{{ category.name }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>   
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            -->
            <label for="#courtorder-category" class="form-label mt-4">Kategorie</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-4">
                <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="bi bi-bookmark-fill"></i>
                </span>
                {% render_field courtorder.category class+="form-control" name="category" hx-get="/check_courtorder_additional_fields/" hx-trigger="change" hx-target="#courtorder-additional-fields" %}
            </div>

            <div id="courtorder-additional-fields"></div>         
            
            <label for="#courtorder-description" class="form-label mt-4">Kurzbeschreibung</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-4">
                <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="bi bi-chat-left-dots"></i>
                </span>
                {% render_field courtorder.description class+="form-control" autocomplete="off" %}
            </div>

            <div class="row align-items-end">
                <div class="col col-1">
                    {% render_field courtorder.show_in_sidebar id="courtorder-show-in-sidebar" class+="form-control form-check form-check-input" %}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="#courtorder-show-in-sidebar">In der Sidebar anzeigen</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            

            <label for="#courtorder-institution" class="form-label mt-4">Gericht</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="input-group mb-4">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                            <i class="bi bi-bank"></i>
                        </span>
                        {% render_field courtorder.institution id="courtorder-institution" class+="form-control" %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" 
                        hx-get="{% url 'add-institution-inline_2' %}"
                        hx-target="#add-court"
                        >
                        Neu...
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="add-court"></div>

            <label for="#courtorder-date" class="form-label">Beschlussdatum</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-4">
                <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
                </span>
                {% render_field courtorder.date id="courtorder-date" type="date" class+="form-control" autocomplete="off" hx-post="/htmx_check_court_order_sign/" hx-trigger="keyup" hx-target="#court-order-sign-error" hx-swap="outerhtml" %}
            </div>

            <label for="#courtorder-delivery-date" class="form-label">Rechtswirksamkeit</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-4">
                <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
                </span>
                {% render_field courtorder.effect_date id="courtorder-delivery-date" type="date" class+="form-control" autocomplete="off" hx-post="/htmx_check_court_order_sign/" hx-trigger="keyup" hx-target="#court-order-sign-error" hx-swap="outerhtml" %}
            </div>

            <label for="#courtorder-next-update" class="form-label">nächste Überprüfung</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-4">
                <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
                </span>
                {% render_field courtorder.next_update id="courtorder-next-update" type="date" class+="form-control" autocomplete="off" hx-post="/htmx_check_court_order_sign/" hx-trigger="keyup" hx-target="#court-order-sign-error" hx-swap="outerhtml" %}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Los gehts</button>
    </div>
</div>

    
{% else %}

<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 id="modal-title" class="modal-title">Neuer Gerichtsbeschluss</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">    

        <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method=POST hx-post="/add_court_order/{{ record.pk }}/" hx-target="#modal-dialog" >
            {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="#courtorder-sign" class="form-label">Bitte geben Sie das Aktenzeichen des Gerichts an:</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-4">
            <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="bi bi-file-text"></i>
            </span>
            {% render_field courtorder.sign id="courtorder-sign" class+="form-control" autocomplete="off" hx-post="/check_courtorder_sign/" hx-trigger="keyup" hx-target="#courtorder-sign-error" hx-swap="outerhtml" %}
        </div>

        <center><div id="courtorder-sign-error"></div></center>






    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Los gehts</button>
    </div>
</div>
  
{% endif %}
```

and the view (still a work in progress):

```py
ef add_court_order(request, record_pk):
    submitted = False
    sign_submitted = False
    record = Record.objects.get(pk=record_pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        new_courtorder = CourtOrderForm(request.POST)
        if new_courtorder.is_valid():
            courtorder = new_courtorder.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/add_court_order/{record.pk}?courtorder_pk={courtorder.pk}')
    else:
        courtorder = CourtOrderForm
        if 'courtorder_pk' in request.GET:
            courtorder_pk = request.GET.get('courtorder_pk')
            courtorder = Record.objects.get(pk=courtorder_pk)
            sign_submitted = True
    
    return render(request, 'add_court_order.html', {'courtorder': courtorder, 'record': record, 'sign_submitted':sign_submitted})
```

I have commented out the two lines in forms.py where I customize `institution` and `category` and this worked, so now I guess I have to change the question:

How do I keep `ForeignKeys` optional when I customized them in `forms.py`as shown above?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], we'd need at least your form class and maybe the view and template to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Django: Optional model form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539694/django-optional-model-form-field) Tl;Dr You've declared the field explicitly in the form, you need to specify `required=False` in the form field if you want to make that optional.

Answer (score 0):

@Abdul Aziz Barkat:
Thank you very much, the linked question solved the problem!

I just added `required=False` to the customized entried in forms.py:

```py
class CourtOrderForm(ModelForm):
    institution = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Institution.objects.filter(category__category__icontains="gericht"), required=False)
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CourtOrderCategory.objects.order_by('name'), required=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = CourtOrder
        fields = (
            'sign',
            'category',
            'description',
            'show_in_sidebar',
            'institution',
            'date',
            'effect_date',
            'next_update',
            'duty_scopes',
            'notes',
            'records',
        )
```

Can you add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the solution?